# How Can I Create A Single function that can create multiple Linked Lists

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

as shown in the code , i have to use 2 similar functions for creating 2 linked lists . isn't there a way i can create as many lists as i want with just one function , i tried using `struct Node **p` and `struct Node *p` as a parameter to the function but the didn't work
can someone help me to create multiple linked lists using this same function
and i want to create a append function not a insert function which asks for position as well.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct  Node
{
    int data = 10 ;
    struct Node *next;
} *first , *second , *third;

void Display(struct Node *p)
{
    while (p)
    {
        cout<<p->data<<" ";
        p = p->next ;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
void Append_1(int elem)
{
    Node* t , *last;
    t = new Node;
    t->data = elem;
    t->next = NULL;
    if(first == 0)
        first = last = t;
    else 
    {
        last->next = t;
        last = t;
    }
}
void Append_2(int elem)
{
    Node* t , *last;
    t = new Node;
    t->data = elem;
    t->next = NULL;
    if(second == 0)
        second = last = t;
    else 
    {
        last->next = t;
        last = t;
    }
}
//void SortMerge(struct Node *p , struct Node *q);

int main()
{
    Append_1(3);
    Append_1(7);
    Display(first);

    Append_2(10);
    Append_2(14);
    Append_2(21);
    Display(second);

    //SortMerge(first , second);
    Display(third);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't tar multiple different languages. Only tag the language you're actually program in.

Comment: As for your problem, why not pass a reference to the list as argument to your function? Similarly like you do for the `Display` function which can display nodes from any of your lists.

Comment: 1. Create class and every time when you create linked list create new instance
2. Add additional parameter - linked list head and your methods will operate on many linked lists

Comment: what do you mean by "i tried using "struct Node p " and " struct Node p " as a parameter to the function but the didn't work"? Can you post out those functions you've tried as well as the error messages you encountered?
Also, please format your question properly, you **CAN** see the preview while editing it.

Comment: A few other notes: Please separate the data, the nodes and the lists into different structures, as that will simplify much of your work with the lists. Also note that `NULL` is the backward compatibility macro from C for a null pointer, in C++ use `nullptr`.

Comment: Those `last` pointers (`last->next = ...`) don't hang around when the function finishes... Turn up warnings and solve those problems.

Comment: Please show what *exactly* you tried, and what *exactly* didn't work,

Comment: *isn't there a way i can create as many lists as i want with just one function* -- `class LinkedList { Node *headNod; ...};  std::vector<LinkedList>  multiple_lists(10);` -- There, I created 10 linked list, with no function required.  If you actually wrote a linked list *class* instead of a naked `Node` class being manipulated with global functions, then all of this would be easily possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class like here:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;
};

class Graph{
    public:
    Graph(int = 0);
    ~Graph();
    void display_left_right();
    void display_right_left();
    void append(int);
    void append_at_pos(int,int);
    void prepend(int);
    int get_num_elt();
    int get_data_at_pos(int);
    private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int num_elt=0;
};

Graph::Graph(int first_data){
    head = new Node;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->previous = NULL;
    head->data = first_data;
    tail = head;
    num_elt++;
}

Graph::~Graph(){
    Node* main_traverser = head;
    while(main_traverser){
        main_traverser = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = main_traverser;
    }
    std::cout <<"Graph deleted!" << std::endl;
}

void Graph::display_left_right(){
    Node* traverser = head;
    while(traverser != NULL){
        std::cout << traverser->data << " ";
        traverser = traverser->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void Graph::display_right_left(){
    Node* traverser = tail;
    while(traverser != NULL){
        std::cout << traverser->data << " ";
        traverser = traverser->previous;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void Graph::append(int new_data){
    Node* add = new Node;
    add->data = new_data;
    add->next = NULL;
    add->previous = tail;
    tail->next = add;
    tail = add;
    num_elt++;
}
void Graph::append_at_pos(int pos, int new_data){
    if(pos > num_elt+1 || pos<=0){std::cout << "Wrong position!" << std::endl; return;}
    if(pos==1){
        prepend(new_data);
        return;
    }
    if(pos==num_elt+1){
        append(new_data);
        return;
    }
    Node* add = new Node;
    Node* traverser = head;
    add->data = new_data;
    for(int i=0; i<pos-2; i++){
        traverser = traverser->next;
    }
    add->next = traverser->next;
    add->previous = traverser;
    traverser->next->previous = add;
    traverser->next = add;
}
void Graph::prepend(int new_data){
    Node* add = new Node;
    add->next = head;
    add->previous = NULL;
    add->data = new_data;
    head->previous = add;
    head = add;
    num_elt++;
}

int Graph::get_num_elt(){
    return num_elt;
}

int Graph::get_data_at_pos(int pos){
    Node* traverser = head;
    if(pos <=0 || pos> num_elt){std::cout << "Wrong position!" << std::endl; return 0;}
    for(int i=0; i<pos-1; i++){
        traverser = traverser->next;
    }
    return traverser->data;
}

main(){
    Graph a(2);
    a.append(3);
    a.append(4);
    a.prepend(1);
    a.display_left_right();
    a.append_at_pos(1,6);
    a.display_left_right();
    std::cout << "data at 1: " << a.get_data_at_pos(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `Graph` is a bit of a strange name for a list, but otherwise this is the right idea. C++ is an Object-Oriented Language, and lists should be classes. The functin to create a list is therefore the constructor of the class.

Comment: Yeaa i tried this , but what i actually mean is that how can i change the values of a pointer , in my case its "first" ,"second" and "third"        i tried using this but it didn;t work  `void Create(struct Node **p , int elem)
{
    Node *t , *last;
    t =  new Node ;
    t->data = elem;
    t->next = NULL;
    if(!*p)
    *p = last = t;
    else 
    {
        last->next = t ;
        last = t ;
    } 
}`

Comment: i mean like why do i have to create 2 append functions for appending in 2 lists

Answer (score 0):

When you say "create multiple linked lists," I think you mean creating nodes to a linked list, which you have 2 append functions. I think the reason you have these 2 functions is because you do not know where to start traversing your linked list. For this reason, I think in your main function you should declare the head of the linked list, a single node that is the start. Set it's data and next to null, and then pass the head value into a function so it can start traversing from the head. Here is a generic append function that adds a node on the end, where the parameters are a reference to the head node, and the value for the new node:

```
void append(Node ** head, int new_data)
{
    Node * select_node = * head;
    // select node is set to the head node, and will traverse until it is at the end
    while (select_node -> next != NULL)
    {
        // select node is set to the next node until it is NULL (end of linked list)
        select_node = select_node -> next;
    }
    // now that select node is the last node, we need to make it's next value a node
    // and that node should be a new node (allocated in heap) with the value of the input value
//and the next value be NULL (because it's the end of the linked list)
    Node * next_node = new Node();
    next_node -> data = new_data;
    next_node -> next = NULL;
    select_node -> next = next_node;
}
```